# Google disc документы в формате docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Я пытаюсь настроить систему в Google disc, в которой люди могли бы вносить информацию в существующие документы в Google docs как в автономном режиме, так и в режиме онлайн, без возможности изменения исходного документа.

Мой первоначальный подход заключался в создании копии документа после его редактирования и сохранении оригинала без изменений. Для этого я создал кнопку с app-скриптом, которая выполняет то, что мне нужно.
Проблема в том, что эта кнопка не видна людям, с которыми я делюсь файлом в режиме "только комментарии".

Есть идеи, что можно использовать здесь или вместо нее?
В принципе, мне нужно, чтобы люди могли заполнять отчеты (которые в .docx), не имея возможности удалить оригинал, а также после того, как у них снова появится интернет - он будет сохранятся в другой папке (ранее назначеной для пользователя) на Google disc.

Спасибо всем, надеюсь, вы поможете мне найти подходящий инструмент.